# Math Behind the Dragon Illusion!

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Dragon illusion has been one of the items presented in the 3rd "Gathering for Gardner". [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiOQaz-JuOY) shows the illusion.

What does it have to do with mathematics?

[image]

Comment: What is the illusion here ? Is it about the head ?

Comment: Watch this youtube video to get surprised! www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiOQaz-JuOY

Comment: very nice ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You should put a link to the youtube video in your question

Comment: Clever editing of the video. :-)

Comment: Simple. The dragon is obviously alive.